# React Hooks - How to test changes on global providers

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-hooks-testing-library

I'm trying to test the following scenario:

- A user with an expired token tries to access a resource he is not authorized
- The resources returns a 401 error
- The application updates a global state  "isExpiredSession" to true

For this, I have 2 providers:

- The authentication provider, with the global authentication state
- The one responsible to fetch the resource

There are custom hooks for both, exposing shared logic of these components, i.e: fetchResource/expireSesssion

When the resource fetched returns a 401 status, it sets the isExpiredSession value in the authentication provider, through the sharing of a setState method.

`AuthenticationContext.js`
    import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

```
const AuthenticationContext = createContext([{}, () => {}]);

const initialState = {
  userInfo: null,
  errorMessage: null,
  isExpiredSession: false,
};

const AuthenticationProvider = ({ authStateTest, children }) => {
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState(initialState);

  return (
    <AuthenticationContext.Provider value={[authStateTest || authState, setAuthState]}>
      { children }
    </AuthenticationContext.Provider>);
};


export { AuthenticationContext, AuthenticationProvider, initialState };
```

`useAuthentication.js`

```
import { AuthenticationContext, initialState } from './AuthenticationContext';


const useAuthentication = () => {
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useContext(AuthenticationContext);
  ...
  const expireSession = () => {
    setAuthState({
      ...authState,
      isExpiredSession: true,
    });
  };
  ...
  return { expireSession };
 }
```

ResourceContext.js is similar to the authentication, exposing a Provider

And the useResource.js has something like this:

```
const useResource = () => {
  const [resourceState, setResourceState] = useContext(ResourceContext);
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useContext(AuthenticationContext);

  const { expireSession } = useAuthentication();

  const getResource = () => {
    const { values } = resourceState;
    const { userInfo } = authState;

    return MyService.fetchResource(userInfo.token)
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.ok) {
          result.json()
            .then((json) => {
              setResourceState({
                ...resourceState,
                values: json,
              });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              setErrorMessage(`Error decoding response: ${error.message}`);
            });
        } else {
          const errorMessage = result.status === 401 ?
            'Your session is expired, please login again' :
            'Error retrieving earnings';
          setErrorMessage(errorMessage);
          expireSession();

        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setErrorMessage(error.message);
      });
  };
  ...
```

Then, on my tests, using react-hooks-testing-library I do the following:

```
  it.only('Should fail to get resource with invalid session', async () => {
    const wrapper = ({ children }) => (
      <AuthenticationProvider authStateTest={{ userInfo: { token: 'FOOBAR' }, isExpiredSession: false }}>
        <ResourceProvider>{children}</ResourceProvider>
      </AuthenticationProvider>
    );
    const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useResource(), { wrapper });

    fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify({}), { status: 401 });

    act(() => result.current.getResource());
    await waitForNextUpdate();

    expect(result.current.errorMessage).toEqual('Your session is expired, please login again');
    // Here is the issue, how to test the global value of the Authentication context? the line below, of course, doesn't work
    expect(result.current.isExpiredSession).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

I have tried a few solutions:

- Rendering the `useAuthentication` on the tests as well, however, the changes made by the Resource doesn't seem to reflect on it.
- Exposing the isExpiredSession variable through the Resource hook, i.e:

```
      return { 
            ...
            isExpiredSession: authState.isExpiredSession,
            ...
       };
```

I was expecting that by then this line would work:

`expect(result.current.isExpiredSession).toBeTruthy();`

But still not working and the value is still false

Any idea how can I implement a solution for this problem?

Comment: would you share a repo?

Answer (score 3):

Author of `react-hooks-testing-library` here.

It's a bit hard without being able to run the code, but I *think* your issue might be the multiple state updates not batching correctly as they are not wrapped in an `act` call.  The ability to `act` on async calls is in [an alpha release of `react` (v16.9.0-alpha.0)](https://github.com/facebook/react/releases/tag/v16.9.0-alpha.0) and we have [an issue tracking it](https://github.com/mpeyper/react-hooks-testing-library/issues/14) as well.

So there may be 2 ways to solve it:

1. Update to the alpha version and a move the `waitForNextUpdate` into the `act` callback

```sh
npm install react@16.9.0-alpha.0
```

```js
  it.only('Should fail to get resource with invalid session', async () => {
    const wrapper = ({ children }) => (
      <AuthenticationProvider authStateTest={{ userInfo: { token: 'FOOBAR' }, isExpiredSession: false }}>
        <ResourceProvider>{children}</ResourceProvider>
      </AuthenticationProvider>
    );
    const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useResource(), { wrapper });

    fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify({}), { status: 401 });

    await act(async () => {
      result.current.getResource();
      await waitForNextUpdate();
    });

    expect(result.current.errorMessage).toEqual('Your session is expired, please login again');

    expect(result.current.isExpiredSession).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

2. Add in a second `waitForNextUpdate` call

```js
  it.only('Should fail to get resource with invalid session', async () => {
    const wrapper = ({ children }) => (
      <AuthenticationProvider authStateTest={{ userInfo: { token: 'FOOBAR' }, isExpiredSession: false }}>
        <ResourceProvider>{children}</ResourceProvider>
      </AuthenticationProvider>
    );
    const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useResource(), { wrapper });

    fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify({}), { status: 401 });

    act(() => result.current.getResource());

    // await setErrorMessage to happen
    await waitForNextUpdate();

    // await setAuthState to happen
    await waitForNextUpdate();

    expect(result.current.errorMessage).toEqual('Your session is expired, please login again');

    expect(result.current.isExpiredSession).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Your appetite for using alpha versions will likely dictate which option you go for, but, option 1 is the more "future proof".  Option 2 may stop working one day once the alpha version hits a stable release.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the anwer.
I have tried updating to the react alpha, however even after updating and changing my code, the error is still there.

Also, I get some warnings... if I just move the `waitForNextUpdate` into `act` like the code you posted I get a warning informing me that await must be inside an async function.
However, if I change the act callback to async I get a warning informing that the act method callback cannot return a Promise.

Comment: oh yeah, I forgot about that part of it.  I've updated the example to show the async `act` call correctly.